# How is HTTPS browsing history monitored?

Tags: networking, security, https, history, decryption

I am researching on how to monitor HTTPS browsing history. I am not a network person, so apologies if I sound ignorant in this issue. I googled the following questions below, but nothing substantial came up:

- HTTPS session tracking
- How are data collected from HTTPS websites?
- how are https websites monitored?

So what I've researched on HTTPS is that it is Confidential. The visitor’s connection is encrypted, obscuring URLs, cookies, and other sensitive metadata.

My question is, can those data and information be tracked and collected and if so, how is it possible?

Also, with HTTPS websites, can you see where are how long are people going to these websites?

If you guys could point me in the right direction, it would really help!

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS ...

Comment: I have looked at the wiki already. Can you pinpoint to a specific section in the link.

Comment: There are so many resources that tell you what HTTPS is and how it works... it really seems like you haven't done any research of your own... https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20https%20work

Comment: I know what HTTPS is and how it works. I need to know how a company/someone can collect data from HTTPS websites. Do they use a server? a software? I saw related questions about HTTPS in this site, but it is on how to evade HTTPS tracking, not how the tracking is done. I am not looking for someone to do my research for me - at the very least, I would like some help in knowing what key words I should be searching for so I have some direction as to where to look.

Comment: What "HTTPS browsing history" are you talking about? What are you trying to accomplish? Super User isn't for research but practical problems.

Comment: The question I am trying to answer is this: Is there a way to collect data from HTTPS websites? From this question: http://superuser.com/questions/103222/am-i-secure-from-network-monitoring-software-if-https-is-used?rq=1      It talks about a man-in-the-middle. Is that what is used to collect encrypted information from HTTPS websites?

Comment: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https may be informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS (HTTP over TLS) provides security while data is moving between the user agent (your browser) and the web server. That's it. It doesn't protect data on the client or server.

HTTPS also only works if done entirely correctly.

> Also, with HTTPS websites, can you see where are how long are people going to these websites?

If you can sniff the network traffic, you can see the domain names / IP addresses that they visit, even if using HTTPS. You can see the time and size of every request and response. You cannot see URL paths or query strings or headers or bodies. But you can make inferences about them based on the size.

> My question is, can those data and information be tracked and collected and if so, how is it possible?

In some cases yes you can be tracked. Some methods include:

1. Get access to the client computer (physical/malware/governmental)
2. Get access to the server computer (physical/malware/governmental)
3. [SSLStrip](https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/)
4. Exploit a flaw in TLS (BREACH, CRIME, Logjam, goto fail, Heartbleed, Freak, Poodle, etc)

What to do about it:

1. Use a dedicated computer for important activities (like banking, healthcare), to avoid getting malware from less important activities, and lock it in a safe
2. Use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to see if the servers you use are reasonably secure
3. Test your browser too: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html
4. Use a browser with a built-in sandbox (Chrome)

Comment: Thank you, this greatly helps! Now I know what to look for.